# NLog with enableArchiveFileCompression doesn't work

Tags: nlog

I'm trying to configure archiving of logs, using NLOg File target

I have the following configuration:

```
<target xsi:type="File"
name="file"
fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${appdomain:format={1\}}.${shortdate}.log"
archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/archives/${appdomain:format={1\}}.Archive.{#}.zip"
archiveEvery="Day"
archiveNumbering="Date"
maxArchiveFiles="30"
enableArchiveFileCompression="True"
encoding="UTF-8"
layout="${longdate} PID:${processid} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} - ${message:withException=false}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION DETAILS\:
 ${newline}################################################################################${newline}${exception: format=ToString,Data: maxInnerExceptionLevel=10: innerFormat=Type,Message,Data }${newline}################################################################################${newline}}" />
```

NLog version is 4.4.12 (the same was behaviour for other NLog 4.x.x versions )

But this configuration doesn't work or works not every time. It doesn't create archives at all or can skip many days. I think the main reason is that our application can complete execution early than archive is created. We start application many times but it lasts several seconds and produces log file about 20MB-30MB per day.

Is there any way to wait until archiving is complete or some other approaches to force archiving to work?

Comment: Would make sense to have a local-file-queue of files needing to be compressed. When a file is finally compressed then it is moved to the final destination. The compression should be handled by a dedicated background-thread, instead of the logging-thread being punished. At startup the background thread will check local-file-queue, and if pending files then it start compression right away. You are welcome to create a GitHub-PullRequest, that implements this.

Comment: But will it help for cases when the main app thread finishes early then background one? Maybe we need also some mechanism to wait for finishing background thread? Synchronous Flush?

Comment: Usually application have 2 secs to complete its stuff before everything is automatically shutdown. This is usually not always enough to complete file-compression. Ofcourse the LogManager.Flush could be called manually by the application before doing normal exit, and the FileTarget-flush can make sure not to return before the pending local-file-queue is empty. If a flush-timeout happens (or crash occurs), then the local-file-queue will wait for next application start.

Comment: Rolf, sounds reasonable. You mentioned that I should create a pull request. But I 'm not familiar with GitHub. It is completely different compared with a Feature request. Right? Or I can also create a Feature request?

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/